What's the best way to auto generate OPENAPI documentation for a Spring boot Jersey project?
I'm developing a simple project with Spring Boot and Jersey for my University course. One of the assignment was to produce the relative OPENAPI documentation.
I did it manually, is there a way to do it with a tool or a maven plugin?
Searching on internet I found some tools to do it with Jersey or with Spring Boot, but not something to do it using both.

I recommend doing a google search on the topic. Seaching for "spring-boot generate openapi documentation", for example, lead me to this baeldung.com article.

@Turing85 as I said I already searched for a solution on the web, and, among others, I found the same article you suggest. It talks about standalone Spring, not with Jersey.

I think Swagger Core can be used with Jersey.
